# Idioms or expressions defining either getting paid fully or being appreciated

Tags: expressions, idioms, proverbs

I am looking for a common English expression/idiom that defines a situation below:
I have done some work for someone, and in return, they are not going to pay me the full payment. Then I will tell them, "**either pay me in full or express your gratitude**" (or pay me nothing so that you are under my debt)

Thanks!

Comment: *Either pay me in full **or you owe me one***. What exactly that outstanding debt of "one" represents is unspecified, but in practice, it'll usually amount to ***whatever** "favour" I ask from you in return for this*. You're not exactly asking for "gratitude" - simply the recognition that *there is a debt which will eventually be repaid*.

Comment: You should please correct the spelling errors errors in your post.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is much scope for using this. "Either pay me in full or I'm taking you to court" seems more likely.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pay+up+or%22&client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ALeKk03g6zj1LuSGCYgt8OQkwjvtk_npbQ:1593372821395&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiF8Y2ooKXqAhU1HTQIHRwSAfUQ_AUoAXoECAsQCQ&biw=1118&bih=519&dpr=1.5

Comment: "Pay up or you will be beholden to me forever" - there are lots of ways to express this but not sure if any are common enough to be idiomatic. It probably depends if you are a gangsta rapper, Disney villain, or come from another subculture because this is unlikely to be universal across all milieus.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! I think you are used to using the wrong word. I should hope they express their *gratitude* even when they pay you. Mere gratitude means you are not getting paid.

Perhaps you mean Pay me in full or *Express your indebtedness* to me.
Explain that you still owe me for what you have not payed.

In U.S. English I might say "Pay me in full or tell me how you are going to make it up to me."

Or "Explain what you are going to do about it."

You either have your pay **or** their *Indebtedness*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the verb **compensate** (or perhaps **make it up to me** or **make up the difference**) to get across the point that you expect *something*, but are willing to leave it up to them to specify what form it will take. You might want to avoid the word *gratitude*—they might suggest it themselves; however, they might come up with something more tangible (e.g. a gift, service, favor) that you would prefer.

**compensate** (v.)

> To pay someone money in exchange for work done, for something lost or
> damaged, or for some inconvenience:
>
> *Our company tries to keep salaries low, and they compensate employees more with bonuses.*
>
> To take the place of something useful or needed with something else of
> similar value:
>
> *When you have a disability, you learn to compensate by doing other things well.*
> [Cambridge](https://Cambrdige)

For example:

> "I would like to know how else you intend to **compensate** me for not paying in full" or "... for not paying the amount we agreed upon."
>
> "I would like to know how you intend to **make it up to me** for not paying in full" or "... for not paying the amount we agreed upon."
>
> "If you are not going to pay me in full, please suggest how you might **make up the difference**."